# How to reset the count of SimplePager in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am using AscyncDataProvider with my Simple Pager which is working fine. Based on the query parameter I am making a separate call to the server but the row count is not working fine. Could some one please tell me how to reset the rowCount of the simplePager.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following api to set the row count

```
simplePager.getDisplay().setRowCount( int rowCount);
```